# While running the Selenium script getting org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

While running my Selenium Script getting Exceptions

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

This gets resolved whenever i uninstall and then install the same Firefox with different version or with same version. it works fine suddenly it stops working and again when i uninstall and install the browser again it starts working.

I'm Not getting why this is happening if there is Selenium and Firefox compatibility issue it should not work even once.

Please let me know if anybody knows how to resolve this issue, I'm just fed up with uninstall and install the the browser again and again or suggest me the most compatible firfox with Selenium selenium-2.53.1